# dtslint fails because of dependency in DefinitelyTyped

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, lint, definitelytyped

I'm working on improving typings for `@testing-library/cypress` in `DefinitelyTyped` after some feedback from my last [PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/37692).

I've added `cypress` as a dependency as its typings is not defined in DefinitelyTyped, but running `dtslint` fails because it runs with `typescript@next`. If I run `dtslint --localTs` with `typescript@3.5.3` there is no error.

`dtslint` results in the following error:

```
Error: Errors in typescript@next for external dependencies:
node_modules/cypress/types/jquery/index.d.ts(8155,87): error TS2344: Type '"button" | "view" | "altKey" | "bubbles" | "cancelable" | "changedTouches" | "ctrlKey" | "detail" | "eventPhase" | "metaKey" | "pageX" | "pageY" | "shiftKey" | "char" | "charCode" | ... 13 more ... | "touches"' does not satisfy the constraint '"repeat" | "button" | "code" | "view" | "y" | "altKey" | "bubbles" | "cancelable" | "changedTouches" | "ctrlKey" | "detail" | "eventPhase" | "metaKey" | "pageX" | "pageY" | "shiftKey" | ... 54 more ... | "DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD"'.
  Type '"toElement"' is not assignable to type '"repeat" | "button" | "code" | "view" | "y" | "altKey" | "bubbles" | "cancelable" | "changedTouches" | "ctrlKey" | "detail" | "eventPhase" | "metaKey" | "pageX" | "pageY" | "shiftKey" | ... 54 more ... | "DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD"'.
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed with this? I guess there is a reason `dtslint` runs with `typescript@next`, but it seems unstable to me. Is the only option to update the `jquery` typings in `cypress`?

The improvements I am working on can be seen [here](https://github.com/simjes/DefinitelyTyped/commit/7e4e024b179facafc57c30595b6b3b80145fdd0d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it needs to be fixed in the bundled typings in Cypress. [Cypress issue #5065](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5065)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.

You can specify the typescript version to use at the top of your `index.d.ts` with the following comment:

```
// TypeScript Version: 3.5
```

Comment: I've already specified version 3.0 in index.d.ts, but it still runs with typescript@next.